# Iptables being changed without rebooting

Tags: iptables, openswan

I configured a tunnel between my network and a remote network with OpenSwan. On my tunnel endpoint, running on Ubuntu, I added iptables rules to disable source NAT (SNAT) when the destination was the remote network. Packets sent from my network to the remote network will be sent with the private IP address as source.

Here's what my NAT table looks like

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target      prot opt source           destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere         ! <remote_network>
```

This all worked fine for a while, but at some point the tunnel was down. It appeared that my more restrictive rule had been replaced by the generic rule that performs SNAT on all packets. Other rules in FORWARD table were also removed. The server has not been rebooted for more than 300 days !

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target      prot opt source           destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere         anywhere
```

I tried adding a script in /etc/network/if-up.d to restore my conf every time the networking service restarted but that didn't help. I also installed the package 'iptables-persistent' but that didn't help either.

My tunnel endpoint is also running OpenVpn for other purposes.

What process is likely to change my iptables like that ? How can I make sure it won't be changed again ?

Comment: I don't remember exactly because I configured it ages ago, but I definitely remember OpenVPN messing up with iptables somehow when bridging networks. Can you check if you experience the same issue even with openvpn turned off?

Comment: Let me second stoned's comment; I know I've seen something a lot like this happen, and ended up just throwing my hands up in dismay.

Comment: Your comments led me to the solution. Thank you. In order to make OpenVpn work with Firestarter, some tweaking is neccesary [Firestarter & VPN](http://www.fs-security.com/docs/vpn.php). Apparently, these rules are reloaded regularly so it is why my rules got removed. I added my rules to the firestarter conf file.